# How can i build a connection between an RMI server and a RESTful web service?

Tags: spring, rest, jax-rs, rmi

So I am trying to understand how to build a connection between a RMI server and a RESTful web service.

My requirement is that , I need to build a web client and a RMI desktop application , which connects to a RESTful web service to conduct crud operation. I only need to use the web application to view the data in the database , but the desktop application needs to be able to conduct CRUD operations.

[image]

The above provided diagram is the architecture I need to follow to develop my application.

For the web client I am able to use an asynchronous web application and use jersey or spring as the RESTful web service,
 but the problem I have is ,

1. What kind of application should I develop in the first place to develop the desktop application ?
2. How can I connect the RMI server and the REST API?

Comment: The RMI server needs to be a REST client. But I don't know why you have it at all. The desktop client can do REST just as easily as the RMI server can.

Comment: The requirements provided is that I need to connect the RMI server to a REST client, so the RMI server needs to be the REST client is that so? , but then how can I create a connection with the web client and the REST API?

Comment: The web client talks RMI to the RMI server, and the RMI server talks REST to the REST server.

Comment: I am a bit unclear could you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: No, I don't think I can. What part of it didn't you understand?

Comment: So what you mean is the web client talks to the RMI server which is the REST client , but shouldn't the RMI server and the REST client be separate?

Comment: That's not only what I meant, it's what I said. Twice. How else can the RMI server talk to to the REST server if it doesn't have a REST client inside it?

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to make both the web client and the desktop application in one project as a maven project?

Comment: Why can't we just call the API server directly from the Desktop app?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha do you mean from the RMI server calling the REST api?

Comment: No, I mean use an HTTP client (like Jersey Client) in the desktop app to call the REST API. Why do you need RMI in the middle?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha it is a requirement provided

Comment: @thumalee Saying it is a requirement doesn't answer the question *why* it is a rqeuirement. It is just circular reasoning.